# How to transfer data from one page to the next?

Tags: javascript, html

I have several sites with different domains. A customer may do something in page a.com/1.html, and some data was generated there. Then the customer may click a link in page a.com/1.html and be redirected to b.com/2.html, while b.com/2.html may be opened in the same window or a new window. Is there any front-end(JavaScript/HTML) method to transfer the data generated in a.com/1.html to b.com/2.html?

As the two page is not in the same domain, cookie/localStorage is not available here, and the next page may be opened in a new window so data could not be stored in window.name temporary, the data may be a bit long and for some reason we could not pass it through URL parameters. I don't need two-way communication between the two pages, what I need is the first page transfer the data to the next page, or the first one store the data in somewhere and the next one get it.

Is there any solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is a POST request a viable solution?

Comment: The next page may be a static page, it could not deal with a POST...

Comment: In that case URL parameters may well be your only point of entry into page 2. Perhaps if you provide a sample of the kind of data you're working with, someone can give you a way to circumvent the "some reason" why this solution wouldn't work. Worth a try, no?

Comment: The data we want to transfer is just only associated with the current page view(eg. "pv_id=abc.123&tracer=1,2,3&timestamp=1325766145818.461"), if we put it in URL parameters and some customer send the URL to someone else or add it into his favorite for a future visit, it can cause errors or dirty logs.

Answer (score 1):

If the data you're trying to transfer can fit in GET parameters, perhaps this is a viable solution:

1. Pass the data along from `a.com` to `b.com` in GET parameters;
2. Save the data at `b.com` in a cookie;
3. Redirect to the **same page** (on `b.com`) without the parameters;
4. Load the data from the cookie.

Comment: The two pages may be in different domains, for example the first page is a.com/1.html, the next page is b.com/2.html, if the data is saved in cookie of a.com, it seems that there is no way to load it in b.com?

Comment: @oldj: I updated the answer to make it more clear. I meant passing the data to `b.com` and **then** saving a cookie. The redirect is **only** to prevent people from sharing or bookmarking the URL with the parameters.

Comment: Got it, thanks! This is indeed a solution, the only problem is it will load the page in b.com twice, this will make two records in the browser history and server-side log and customers may notice the extra redirection, the user experience is not so nice...

Answer (score 0):

Try window.showModalDialog() or window.showModallessDialog() in page a.com/1.html to open b.com/2.html in a new window or browser tag. The second param of the tow functions may be an object, in which you can put your datas from a.com/1.html and transfer it to b.com/2.html~~

Comment: window.showModalDialog and window.showModallessDialog is IE only, and sometime we need to open the next page in the same window, it means  a.com/1.html will not exist any more when user see b.com/2.html. It seems that these two method don't work very well in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Both sites can use flash SharedObject to store data. They can share datas if only they use swf files in the same domain.

However，flash is not an available solution for ios device. So think about it before using.